# HTML positioning of divs above image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a large image, and a bunch of divs that I'm using as fake buttons on top of said image.  Currently, I'm using absolute positioning to place the divs where I want them to be, but I've got a lot of divs, and finding the x/y coords by trial and error is time I don't want to take.  Is there an easier way to position them, or am I stuck?

I'm using jQuery and Javascript in this project, so these can be used for solutions.

CSS:

```
#test0 {
position:absolute;
    left:381px;
    bottom:100px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="image">
    <div id="test0" class="button" onclick="$('#modal').dialog('open');" style="postion:absolute">
        Click me to test Modal!
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="button" onclick="$('#modal').dialog('open');" style="postion:absolute">
        Click me to test the same Modal!
    </div>
    <img src="testImage.jpg" alt="testtest" />
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of inputs would you expect to provide to a "programmatic" solutions which wouldn't include the actual coordinates?

Comment: Let me get this clear: you want the divs to be put on the right places but you don't want to actually tell the browser where is this right place? So, how do you expect it to find it? Magic? Also, why don't you use `$(".button").click(function() {$("#modal").dialog("open");});` instead of the traditional event definition?

Comment: I'm new to web design like this.  Is there some way I could drag the elements?

Comment: Nope, you will get horrible code. Use your brain, and learn CSS. You are gonna need it in the future anyway :)!

Comment: Alright, guess I've got my work cut out for me.  Thanks though.

Comment: You can edit the CSS through Chrome's Inspector, it makes the trial and error go faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="image">
<div id="container-of-fake-divs">

<div class="fake-div">FAKE DIV</div>
<div class="fake-div">FAKE DIV</div>

</div>

<img src="image.jpg" />

</div>
```

STYLE:

```
#image { position:relative; } 
#container-of-fake-divs { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
.fake-div { display:block; }
```